# How to send only one request after resetting several fields?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I use reactive forms and try to reset 5 specific fields, but my form listens to any changes and send a request. And if I reset 5 fields, my form sends 5 requests. But I want to send only one request after all changes.

```
this.subs = form.get('city').valueChanges.subscribe(city => {
            form.get('property').reset(null, {
              emitEvent: false,
              onlySelf: true
            });

            form.get('cars').reset(null, {
              emitEvent: false,
              onlySelf: true
            });

            form.get('tariff').reset(null, {
              emitEvent: false,
              onlySelf: true
            });

            form.get('version').reset(null, {
              emitEvent: false,
              onlySelf: true
            });
          });
```

What am I do wrong?

PS: I use ngx-formly to organize forms.

Comment: Where are you sending the requests?

Comment: You can create new for instead of resetting all properties.

Comment: @xyz there is subscription on change of each field in the form. It doesn't matter.

Comment: @shadowman_93 I don't reset all properties. I reset only 5 properties from 8.

Comment: @panay Doesn't matter? please show us the full code, you say there are 5 requests being sent, show us where are you sending those?

Answer (score 0):

Something beyond what you've provided must be causing the issue. Something like this works fine:

```
 form = new FormGroup({
    a: new FormControl('a'),
    b: new FormControl('b'),
    c: new FormControl('change me'),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subs = [
      this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(v => console.log('form value change', v)),
      this.form.get('c').valueChanges.subscribe(() => { 
        console.log('reset');

        this.form.get('a').reset('d', { emitEvent: false });
        this.form.get('b').reset('e', { emitEvent: false });
      }),
    ];
  }
```

here's a working stackblitz: https://angular-awifgk.stackblitz.io